# Помогите | if and else Python |

Tags: python, if

Хочу чтобы если команда выполнялась выводился текст с благодарностью за использование, а если произошла ошибка выводился текст с извинением.

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
videoClip = VideoFileClip("09990.mp4")
videoClip.write_gif("09990.gif")
if videoClip.write_gif is True:
    print("Thanks for using!")
else:
    print("Oh no!")
```

В итоге когда всё работает он выводит извинение. А моментов где команда не работала у меня не возникало.

Comment: Когда команда выполняется то делается файл .gif, если нет то по сути не получается файл .gif.

Comment: @CrazyElf `if videoClip.write_gif is True: это всегда будет выполняться, если write_gif это функция, т.е. не пустая сущность` - нет, это никогда не будет выполняться, т.к. функция не является объектом `True`. Всегда бы выполнялось, если бы было `if videoClip.write_gif:`

Comment: @insolor Да, немного напутал, `is` не сработает, точно. Удалю комментарий, чтобы не путать никого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from pathlib import Path
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

videoClip = VideoFileClip("09990.mp4")

# Не силен в либе moviepy поэтому не могу сказать возвращается ли здесь какое то значение
videoClip.write_gif("09990.gif")

# Поэтому просто предлагаю проверить наличие файла
if Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("09990.gif").exists():
    print("Thanks for using!")
else:
    print("Oh no!")
```